# how to use values returned by Swift function

Tags: swift, function

I am trying to use a Swift function to place a circle in the centre of a view so it is always on centre regardless of screen size. I can draw the circle at a point defined by a set of arbitrary x and y values but I need the function to supply these values instead.

I have created a function called `screenCentre()` to read and return two parameters that are the centre coordinates. However Xcode warns that the

`“Result of call to screenCentre() is unused”`

I’ve worked through [Swift tutorials on functions and closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html) and understand how to pass arguments to a function but I am still not clear how to use values returned by this function.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

   let radius = CGFloat(20)
   let fillColour  = UIColor.clear.cgColor
   let lineColour  = UIColor.red.cgColor
   let lineWidth  = 1.0

   var x: CGFloat?
   var y: CGFloat?

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       screenCentre()
       print(screenCentre())

      // arbitrary set of coordinates used to draw circle

      circle(x: 150, y: 170)

   }

   func screenCentre() -> (x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat)
   {
      return (self.view.bounds.size.width / 2, self.view.bounds.size.height / 2)
   }

   func circle(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat) {
       let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: x,y: y), radius: radius, startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true)

       let shapeLayer          = CAShapeLayer()
       shapeLayer.path         = circlePath.cgPath

       shapeLayer.fillColor    = fillColour
       shapeLayer.strokeColor  = lineColour
       shapeLayer.lineWidth    = CGFloat(lineWidth)

       view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
   }
}
```

**UPDATE**

By declaring a constant I am able to use values returned by this function. Sam_M and Kevin Bunarjo answered the question as asked.

However Daniel T and PEEJWEEJ both identified a related problem I hadn’t recognised. Once I applied fixits the extension solution offered by Daniel T now gives me a way to rotate the screen around the centre. So I marked it as the best answer. Thanks to everyone who contributed.

Here is the updated code.

```
    let centre = UIScreen.main.centre
    circle(x: centre.x, y: centre.y)
}

func screenCentre() -> CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.midX, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.midY)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `screenCentre()` function won't work in `viewDidLoad` because the `view` is not yet sized to the screen, therefore its center is not in the middle of the screen.

Use this instead:

```
func screenCentre() -> CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.midX, y: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.midY)
}
```

Note that I am using a CGPoint instead of a tuple, but the effect is the same. Also, the above function doesn't need to be in your view controller or any other class since it doesn't reference `self`. It can be a global function.

Since Swift style guidelines encourage making methods over global functions, you might prefer to put the function in an extension like this:

```
extension UIScreen {
    var centre: CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
    }
}
```

Which can be called like this:

```
let centre = UIScreen.mainScreen().centre
print(centre)
```

Comment: If there are several views that need circles, make them all subclasses of your circle view, or add a circle view to each of them.

Answer (score 1):

In your ViewDidLoad method, you are only calling the method, but not storing the returned values. All you need to do to fix this is to create a variable and assign it to the call of your function.

Example:

```
let center = screenCentre()
print(center)
```

Now, the variable center will contain the coordinates of your screen's center. And in subsequent code, you can use center like you would with any other variable.

Answer (score 1):

Your `screenCenter` function returns a tuple containing two `CGFloat` values. These values are labeled `x` and `y` so you can access them by name when querying the function’s return value.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let center = screenCentre()
    //center.x contains the x value returned from screenCenter
    //center.y contains the y value returned from screenCenter

    circle(x: center.x , y: center.y)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is use the _ to discard the return value from the function if you have no need for the value being return.

```
let _ = screenCentre()
```

Comment: You missed an `=`. Also, this solution is fully correct but doesn't make any sense to do if your function doesn't mutate anything like this `screenCentre` function doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [UIViews have a center attribute](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622627-center), so you don't need to calculate it.

Second, the behavior may be inconsistent if changing it with viewDidLoad, and won't react to any changes to size/rotation.

I would recommend making a subClass of UIView that manages drawing the circle and doing something like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var circle: CircleView?

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        centerCircle()
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        centerCircle()
    }

    func centerCircle() {
        circle?.center = self.view.center
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. See my edit. I am still trying this approach as I have several UIViews that need circles.

Comment: I finally worked out how to make a subClass of UIView and have a new question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40059009/why-does-uiview-not-stay-on-centre-while-it-rotates]

Comment: I finally created a subClass of UIView that draws buttons arranged in a circle and it almost works [ see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40558939/how-do-i-rotate-a-group-of-buttons-programmatically-in-swift].